# What's the max level on a gamer's profile on PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn

I noticed that most of my online friends on PS3 are around level 5 or 6 (from acquiring trophies) when I see their profile. What is the max level you can achieve?  What is the benefit for having high levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no benefit really, it's just to show how many games you've played and/or completed.  I've seen people as high as 15 on mine (I'm at 12 now).

Comment: I thought Sony had plans for players with higher levels? Like access to pre-released demos and discounted games?

Comment: That is now for Playstation Plus users I believe.

Comment: The best thing about PSN levels isn't getting access to pre-release demos and discounts, it's showing everybody online that i don't.

Answer (score 7):

I'm level 16 (I have 35 platinums) but the guy with the greatest amount of trophies on Earth, Hakoom, is level 36 and has 170 platinums. Check out [his PS3 Trophy Card page](http://ps3trophycard.com/profile/Hakoom).

Comment: You get an up vote for 35 platinums.  Holy plattys!

Comment: 170 platinums?! Seriously who has time? haha

Comment: Actually Hakoom Is Second In The World Roughdawg4 Has The Most Platnums With 449

Answer (score 2):

There's some explanation @ [extremeps3.com](http://www.xtremeps3.com/2009/12/21/playstation-3-trophy-system-explained/)